# SQL - I have two date strings the return len(9), m/dd/yyyy and mm/d/yyyy. What would help choose the formatting?

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is kinda hard to fill in the backstory. I'm using software that only recognizes fixed dates in mm/yyyy or m/yyyy format but it can read linked dates from a table in MS Access. In the program you have the option to convert the Access linked dates to fixed dates stored in the software. When it converts to a fixed value it can write the date in several variations but the one that's giving me trouble is when it writes in either of these two formats "m/dd/yyyy" or "mm/d/yyyy" since both of these return a length of 9. The code below is how I handle the other formats with length 6,7,8, or 10. I only noticed the error with len 9 because I finally had a situation where it wrote the date as "m/dd/yyyy" and it caused errors in the software because my query "corrected" the date into "m//yyyy" format. I have no control of how it writes the date. The software company knows about the issue and is addressing it in the next update but I have no idea when that will rollout so I need a workaround until then.

Using the method below will return either "m//yyyy" or "mm/yyyy". How can I make it choose to handle the "m/dd/yyyy" format to output "m/yyyy" instead of having the two backslashes? This isn't my code, someone on here wrote it in response to a previous question. I'm not very competent in any programming language but I have a basic understanding of functions.

```
IIf(Len([Expression])=6,"0" & [Expression],
IIf(Len([Expression])=7,[Expression],
IIf(Len([expression])=8,Left([Expression],1) & "/" & Right([expression],4),
IIf(Len([expression])=9,Left([Expression],2) & "/" & Right([expression],4),
IIf(Len([expression])=10,Left([Expression],2) & "/" & Right([expression],4))))))
```

My guess was to include a nested AND function or something like this but I don't know how to get that to work properly and then I'd have to do something like an IfElse statement to handle the "mm/d/yyyy" format. I'm sure there's a more efficient way to get to the solution and I would appreciate the help from someone who actually knows what they are doing instead of me fumbling through it and banging my head on my desk for the next month.

```
If Len[Expression]=9 AND Left[Expression],2 = "/", Left([Expression],1) & "/" & Right([Expression],4) Else Left([Expression],2) & "/" & Right([Expression],4)
```

Comment: This question desperately needs sample data and expected result. [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: I'm not sure what else to provide that isn't included. Dates written to a table in m/dd/yyyy format end up getting converted to m//yyyy because the query was designed to convert mm/dd/yyyy formats to mm/yyyy. So I need it to write 9/01/2021 as 9/2021 instead of the 9//2021 that it's currently doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a Replace function for items that are 9 chars long:

```
IIf(Len([expression])=9,Replace(Left([Expression],2) & "/" & Right([expression],4), "//","/"),
```

Comment: This appears to have worked perfectly. Thank you. How would you find the dates if they weren't in a fixed position, or an unknown length and unknown left or right?

Comment: With your scenario, it would have to be trial and error to get it in a format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Always handle date and time as *Date*, not *Text*, not numbers, no exceptions.

So, *format* your true date value (the value you can read) to the required text format:

```vb
TextMonthYear = Format([YourTrueDate], "mm\/yyyy")
```